# Powerapps - Drop Down value not getting updated

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown, powerapp

I have a PowerApps form which contains a "Status" column connected to "Status" column in SharePoint list.

Now,I want to add a new Status value. I added a new value to the "Status" column in SharePoint list and this new value is not reflecting in PowerApps form.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the whole card from the beginning and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by doing the below:

Created a new datasource (View --> DataSource-->Add New Datasource) --> Refreshed the datasource --> Updated the Status column in Powerapps to use the new datasource